# I have two first given names but when I booked a flight i only put one of my first names

Tags: air-travel

I am flying from Canada to the Philippines and then back for a month. However I might have done a stupid mistake when booking the ticket. I have two first names, but when booking the ticket I omitted one of the first names, being in a hurry.

So my passport reads:

GIVEN NAMES: Michael John
SURNAME: Alvarez

But I booked the ticket as

First name: Michael
Last name: Alvarez

Would this be an issue? I contacted the agency to change the name but after 3 phone calls they told me to contact the airline. However in case there's a fee, I was thinking to see if it's even necessary to make the amendment.

Comment: I almost never enter my second (given) name when buying plane tickets, but I do read whether they ask for 'first name' or 'given names'.

Comment: But did you just board just fine without your second given name?

Comment: Every time. Not even questions asked.

Comment: I must add that I give the official first name and not my usual one, which is a variation on the official name.

Answer (score 6):

**No**, it's not an issue.  Second/middle names are typically ignored for airline tickets.

You do, however, need to make sure the name you enter matches your passport exactly for any visa/ETA applications.

Answer (score 4):

Most people in France have multiple given names. I have three.

I don’t think I’ve ever provided anything but my “usual” given name (which, like for many people, happens to be the first one).

It may be a bit more difficult if your “usual” given name is not the first one, or even not one of your “official” given names. Some passports used to allow for that (french passports used to have the usual given name underlined, but I believe they stopped doing that a decade or two ago).

But in your case, giving just the first of your given names, nobody will care or even notice.